# Is Private key generate during CSR Creation for Signing Certificate?

Tags: private-key, csr, code-signing-certificate

I have created the CSR for my Signing Certificate. During CSR creation, the CSR file saved on my system. But i couldn't find where is the Private key file. I am following the below URL instruction to create CSR file. Anyone help me with these how to check and find Private key file.
https://in.godaddy.com/help/windows-generate-csr-for-code-or-driver-signing-certificate-7282

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You get to  choose where to export the private key to

Answer (score 0):

In Windows the private key is generated when you use the snap-in to generate the CSR.  The private key is stored (encrypted) at:

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\Your SID
```

or

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Crypto\Keys
```

If there are multiple files in that folder, look for one with a date and time close to when you generated your CSR.